# Finding contour from depth image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am a newbie in image processing. I have a depth image which has been converted to grayscale like below:

[From depth to grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWUSQ.jpg)

through

```
depth_image_raw = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
to_grayscale = cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image_raw, alpha=0.30)
ret, Thresh = cv2.threshold(to_grayscale, 60, 155, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(to_grayscale, contours, 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

which didn't work. When I do `print(countours)` I can see list of coordinates but it's not drawn by `cv2.drawCountours`.

Where am I going wrong?

I tried to do something like this : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWUSQ.jpg): [Detect approximately objects on depth map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094594/detect-approximately-objects-on-depth-map)

Comment: Are you displaying the image with `cv2.imshow`?

Comment: can we have a complete code with original image to play with ?

Comment: @stateMachine Yes via cv2.imshow

Comment: @pippo1980 Thats the output image from the camera. The camera is a RealSense D435

Comment: yep I know, but imports are missing and it's not that we all have a camera, so to test your code and hopefully understand anything about pyrealsense2 I need ''depth_frame.get_data()'' to test your code, I understand its a stream from the suite but here we should talk about code that works i.e. input code output. Sorry about my rant but I get frustrated when trying to understand new stuffs

Comment: why cv2.drawContours(to_grayscale, contours, 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)  specify counturs color (0, 0, 255) when we are talking about grayscale image ?

Comment: @pippo1980 The depth_frame.get_data() will give you raw <pyrealsense2.frame Z16 #1433> which later converted to an array `depth_image = np.asanyarray(colorizer.colorize(depth_frame).get_data())`

I found another link : http://grauonline.de/wordpress/?page_id=3065

Sorry mate. I tried to post the whole code but unable to do so

Comment: don't worry, hope somebody better steps in

Answer (score 0):

tried to recreate your issues starting from[Detect approximately objects on depth map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094594/detect-approximately-objects-on-depth-map);

input image:

[image: input_image_from_Detect approximately objects on depth map-RESIZED]

here my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jun  9 08:20:40 2021

@author: Pietro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898354/finding-contour-from-depth-image


codice non utilizzabile manca import e immagine originale 
"""



import cv2

imagez1 = cv2.imread('1tCjh_resized.png') #from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094594/detect-approximately-objects-on-depth-map

print(imagez1.dtype,'   ',imagez1.shape)  

cv2.imshow('pippo',imagez1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

imagez = cv2.imread('1tCjh_resized.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094594/detect-approximately-objects-on-depth-map  

print(imagez.dtype,'   ',imagez.shape)  

cv2.imshow('pippoZ',imagez)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


ret,th = cv2.threshold(imagez,127,255, 1)


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print(contours)
cv2.drawContours(imagez, contours, 0, (0, 0, 255), 2) #black contours
# cv2.drawContours(imagez, contours, 0, (255, 0, 0), 2) #white contours



cv2.imshow('pippoZZ',imagez)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

my question is: why cv2.drawContours(to_grayscale, contours, 0, (0, 0, 255), 2) specify counturs color (0, 0, 255) when we are talking about grayscale image ?

SO I GUESS THE CULPRIT IS HERE:

```
depth_image_raw = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
to_grayscale = cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image_raw, alpha=0.30)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pippo1980 for taking your time to try it out. I also highly doubted the cv2.convertScaleAbs. The original depth image (without being colourized is useless). I am trying another method by using bitwise masking. I will put the result here.